# how to start a stack on reboot of the host without configuring restart: unless-stopped?

Tags: docker-compose

Using `restart: unless-stopped` seems to result in an unhealthy container dropping and restarting indefinitely.

I want my compose stack to start when the host boots and stop if the internal process exited.

Is this possible, or should I write an OS startup script to launch the docker compose stack manually on boot?

Comment: Your options are to use the restart policy, or arrange for something to call `docker compose up` at startup (e.g. a startup script or systemd unit). I would personally stick with the restart policy.